# Youtube api json date published error - 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

Tags: json, date, youtube-api

In the linked [JSON](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLF7D9F274F1E5DD4B?alt=json) file from the YouTube API, the published date is wrong:  `"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"`

But on the [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOMfhqY3Nwo&feature=youtube_gdata) it is correct: `"Published on Aug 10, 2012 by Privalia"`

There are actually 2 videos, and the published date is sent in these nodes (look at the raw JSON to see what I am referring to): 
`feed.entry.0.published` and `feed.entry.1.published`

Oddly, when I try another playlist of another user the published date is correct. Is this a YouTube API error?

Comment: It looks like it is an error. Even viewing the videos [individual entry](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLF7D9F274F1E5DD4B/PLiwUMPElA1wzhg4We4T2MN93dp2ICUR5d?alt=json) didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 1):

The `published` tag in a playlist feed corresponds to the time that the video was added to the playlist, not to the time when the video was uploaded to YouTube.

If you look at the video entry for that specific video id, the `published` value looks correct:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/yOMfhqY3Nwo?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true

I don't know why there isn't a timestamp available that corresponds to when the video was added to that playlist, but hopefully now that you know what that tag is meant to indicate it's not as important.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how that published date is the 0 of the Unix timestamp world I would say yes, it's probably their bug.